# C# Open Source RSS Library

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, rss

I am looking for some open source .net libraryies which makes publishing and consuming RSS feeds easier. I have worked with .net syndication api but just finding if there is something which makes it easier to work with RSS in .net

Thanks.

Comment: Requests for libraries are not considered constructive - these change on a regular basis and personal choice and opinion make it subjective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello you can try with these link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943480.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed.aspx

You can also view this article

http://www.rssdotnet.com/documents/code_examples.html